# See Full Exception String In Error Message

Tags: db2

Right now I am trying to use HTTPGETCLOB function to pull data from an API. The problem is that the resulting error message does not show the whole exception string from the server. Below is the error that I am getting. I just want to see the whole sentence in quotes after the word exception, so the HTTP response code. The database is DB2 v10.5.4 and I am using data studio version 4.1.2.

Error Code:

> Procedure or user-defined function "DB2XML.HTTPGETCLOB", specific name "HTTPGETCLOBNONXML" aborted with an exception "Server returned HTTP response cod".. SQLCODE=-4302, SQLSTATE=38501, DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: Check `db2diag.log` and the `.nfy` log for your DB2 instance -- there may be more information there.

Comment: You can also use db2 ? <errorcode> on the command line to get DB2 to write out some specifics related to the error code. But you have to transform the "negative" codes. Prepend SQL. Make the number positive. Prefix zeros if less than four numbers. And add an N to the end. So in your case it would be db2 ? SQL4302N.